# Flutter application freezes after notifyListeners

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm trying to write a simple Flutter app using the Google Maps plugin. I need to use multiple BLoC/ChangeNotifier objects in order to manage the object shown on-screen.

The issue comes out when I call `notifyListeners()` on a ChangeNotifier. The method which calls `notifyListeners()` completes its execution, and then the app freezes completely (no widget update, unable to interact with existing widgets).

I've tried to understand where's the problem: the only thing I understood is that it works fine while `CompaniesData` (which is the ChangeNotifier that causes the problem) is empty.

```
class CompaniesData extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map<MarkerId, Company> _companiesMap;

  set companies(Set<Company> companies) {
    _companiesMap = companies != null
        ? Map.fromIterable(
            companies,
            key: (company) => MarkerId(company.id.toString()),
            value: (company) => company,
          )
        : null;
    notifyListeners();
    ;
  }

  bool get available => _companiesMap != null;

  Company companyWithId(MarkerId id) => available ? _companiesMap[id] : null;

  Map<MarkerId, Company> get companiesIfAvailable =>
      available ? _companiesMap : Map();

  Iterable<Company> companiesFromIds(BuildContext context, Set<int> ids) {
    Set<int> idsCopy = Set.from(ids);
    return companiesIfAvailable.entries
        .where((entry) => idsCopy.remove(entry.value.id))
        .map<Company>((entry) => entry.value);
  }
}
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Consumer<CompaniesData>(
          builder: (context, data, child) {
            return BlocBuilder(
              bloc: BlocProvider.of<ShownCompaniesBloc>(context),
              builder: (context, shownCompaniesState) {
                return BlocBuilder(
                  bloc: BlocProvider.of<FavoriteCompaniesBloc>(context),
                  builder: (context, favoriteCompaniesState) {
                    return BlocBuilder(
                      bloc: BlocProvider.of<MapPropertiesBloc>(context),
                      builder: (context, mapPropertiesState) {
                        CompaniesData data =
                            Provider.of<CompaniesData>(context, listen: false);
// ...
```

As you can see, the build method contains multiple nested BLoC/Consumer objects.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _fetchCompanies();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _fetchCompanies() {
    findUser().then((location) {
      Set<Company> companies = Set.from([Company.fake()]);
      // CompaniesData.companies is a setter, which calls
      // notifyListeners
      _companiesData.companies = companies;
    });
  }
```

I don't get error messages, exception, my app simply dies after the end of the execution of the callback given to `findUser().then()`.

EDIT:

I changed the code a little bit, and I figured out that the problem isn't `notifyListeners` (or at least it isn't now).

```
final Completer<Map<MarkerId, Company>> _companiesData = Completer();

_AeroMainViewState() {
    findUser()
        .then(_fetchCompanies)
        .then((companies) => _companiesData.complete(Map.fromIterable(
              companies,
              key: (company) => MarkerId(company.id.toString()),
              value: (company) => company,
            )));
  }

  Future<Set<Company>> _fetchCompanies(LatLng location) async =>
      Set.from([Company.fake()]);
```

```
// ...
child: FutureBuilder<Map<MarkerId, Company>>(
          future: _companiesData.future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            // this builder function isn't called at all
            // when the Completer _companiesData is completed
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return Provider<Map<MarkerId, Company>>.value(
                  value: snapshot.data,
                  child: // ...
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          }),
// ...
```

Removing the ChangeNotifier doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use `listen: false` to obtain the CompaniesData?

Comment: Is there a reason to set it to `true` when I also use `Consumer`? EDIT: to `true`

Comment: Ah indeed, I've just realized you used a Consumer too (weird idea btw. you don't need both)

Comment: Is `notifyListener` finishing properly, or is the app stuck there?

Comment: I read that `listen: true` calls `setState` when something changes, I thought that it isn't compatible with `StatelessWidget` then

Comment: It is, don't worry. Even stateless widgets have a "setState". It's just not public.

Comment: `notifyListener` returns properly, in fact if I append something after `_companiesData.companies = companies;` it's executed.

Comment: I still don't see any obvious issue. If you open the [devtools](https://github.com/flutter/devtools), do you see anything?

Comment: If I open devtools after `notifyListener` it behaves like there's nothing in execution.

Comment: I don't think I can help with this without being able to run the code. Do you mind making a small repository containing only the necessary code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The app does not compile

Comment: I'm sorry, I uploaded an older version. I just updated the code. Sorry again

Answer (score 0):

I post my error for future reference. I was doing this in a class:

```
static Stream<Obj1> stream() async* {
    while (true) {
      yield Obj1();
    }
  }

_subscription = Obj1.stream().listen((event) {
   // do something...
}
```

Since the Stream contains potentially an infinite number of objects, the subscription to that stream was blocking the main (and only) thread.